# C# Byte Calculator

Tags: c#, byte, calculator

My problem is that for example when im gonna add `0x02` to `0xFF`, then I get value `0x101`, which is right ofcourse, but is it somehow possible to get value `0x01` from `0xFF + 0x02`. So if value goes above `0xFF`, it will reset itself to `0x00`.

Comment: Do you have any code? I would do something like `a = 0xFF; b = 0x02; c = (a+b) & 0xFF;`

Comment: I’ll try it when i’m home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod it by 0x100

```
result = (0x02+0xff)%0x100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a `byte` let's *cast* to `byte` (and switch `IntegerOverflowException` on possible *overflow* off with a help of `unchecked`):

```
byte a = 0x02;
byte b = 0xFF;

// unchecked: do not throw exception on overflow 
byte result = unchecked((byte) (a + b));
```

Or (if you have *many* operations to perform):

```
byte a = 0x02;
byte b = 0xFF;

unchecked {
  byte result1 = (byte) (a + b);
  byte result2 = (byte) (2 * a + b);
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i’ll try it when i’m home and will let u know if it solves my problem.